# Delphi ADO query - how to search for AD users with specific bits in userAccountControl

Tags: sql, delphi, search, bit-manipulation, ado

I am using delphi 10.4 and using TADOConnection and TADOCommand component to access Active Directory data.  I need to search for user accounts with a specific bit set in userAccountControl filed (i.e. "must change password on next logon" or "disabled" etc).

I have a working query that will search for user accounts where userAccountControl has a specific value, but I need a query that returns ONLY the users with a specific bit set.

For example, `"select sAMAccountName,userAccountControl from 'LDAP://DC=AD,DC=LOCAL' where userAccountControl='514' "` will return all normal disabled users but will miss users who are disabled, but have other bits set in `"userAccountControl"`.  I'd like to be able to construct a query that can ONLY return user IDs with a certain bit set in `userAccountControl`.

I saw example code for Powershell, vbscript etc that is supposed to achieve something similar: `"(&(objectCategory=computer)(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=8192))""`  but it does not work in Delphi.

Any pointers are greatly appreciated
Thank you

Comment: In SQL the bitwise AND is `&`. So  `userAccountControl & 2 = 2` for example would check only the disabled flag. The `&` part masks out all other bits but the one in question and `=` makes sure desired bit was set.

Comment: Thank you Brian, you are correct, and as you can see from my question, the syntax of my SQL statement is using & and the statement works fine in Powershell. However it does NOT work in Delphi - and that's what I'd like to resolve.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I use a TADOQuery instead of a TADOCommand, adding a calculated TStringField (*CalcUserAccountControl*) of length 200, and declaring the following type and constants:
(you can check the values of every flag at [UserAccountControl property flags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/useraccountcontrol-manipulate-account-properties))

```
    type
  TControlFlags = (  SCRIPT, ACCOUNTDISABLE, HOMEDIR_REQUIRED, LOCKOUT, PASSWD_NOTREQD,
                     PASSWD_CANT_CHANGE, ENCRYPTED_TEXT_PWD_ALLOWED, TEMP_DUPLICATE_ACCOUNT,
                     NORMAL_ACCOUNT, INTERDOMAIN_TRUST_ACCOUNT, WORKSTATION_TRUST_ACCOUNT,
                     SERVER_TRUST_ACCOUNT, DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWORD, MNS_LOGON_ACCOUNT,
                     SMARTCARD_REQUIRED, TRUSTED_FOR_DELEGATION, NOT_DELEGATED,
                     USE_DES_KEY_ONLY, DONT_REQ_PREAUTH, PASSWORD_EXPIRED,
                     TRUSTED_TO_AUTH_FOR_DELEGATION, PARTIAL_SECRETS_ACCOUNT);
...
const
  //Bit position of every flag
  BitControlFlag : Array [TControlFlags] of Integer =
  (0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 26);
  //Description of every flag
  StrControlFlag : Array [TControlFlags] of string =
  ('|SCRIPT', '|ACCOUNTDISABLE', '|HOMEDIR_REQUIRED', '|LOCKOUT', '|PASSWD_NOTREQD',
   '|PASSWD_CANT_CHANGE', '|ENCRYPTED_TEXT_PWD_ALLOWED', '|TEMP_DUPLICATE_ACCOUNT',
   '|NORMAL_ACCOUNT', '|INTERDOMAIN_TRUST_ACCOUNT', '|WORKSTATION_TRUST_ACCOUNT',
   '|SERVER_TRUST_ACCOUNT', '|DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWORD', '|MNS_LOGON_ACCOUNT',
   '|SMARTCARD_REQUIRED', '|TRUSTED_FOR_DELEGATION', '|NOT_DELEGATED',
   '|USE_DES_KEY_ONLY', '|DONT_REQ_PREAUTH', '|PASSWORD_EXPIRED',
   '|TRUSTED_TO_AUTH_FOR_DELEGATION', '|PARTIAL_SECRETS_ACCOUNT');

...
```

After that, at the OnCalcFields method of the TADOQuery, just check the bit at the UserAccountControl field from the query,

```
procedure TForm2.TADOQuery1CalcFields(DataSet: TDataSet);
var
  CurrentUAC : Integer;
  StrUAC : String;
  ControlFlags : TControlFlags;
begin
  CurrentUAC := TADOQuery1.FieldByName('userAccountControl').AsInteger;

  for var aControlFlag := low(ControlFlags) to high(ControlFlags) do
    if CurrentUAC and (1 shl BitControlFlag[aControlFlag]) <> 0 then
      strUAC := strUAC + StrControlFlag[aControlFlag];

  TADOQuery1.FieldByName('CalcUserAccountControl').Value := strUAC;
end;
```

At the calculated fiel I got a string with every flag of the UserAccountControl, something like:

```
|PASSWD_NOTREQD|WORKSTATION_TRUST_ACCOUNT
|WORKSTATION_TRUST_ACCOUNT|DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWORD
|ACCOUNTDISABLE|PASSWD_NOTREQD|WORKSTATION_TRUST_ACCOUNT
```

With that in mind you can use the CalculatedField value in order to filter the result set to show only those UserAccountControl flags you require.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Using TADOQuery you can set `Filtered := True` and add an `OnFilterRecord` method in order to get only those records with a specific bit at the `UserAcountControl` field, like the following code:

```
procedure TForm2.TADOQuery1FilterRecord(DataSet: TDataSet; var Accept: Boolean);
var
  CurrentUAC : Integer;
const
  ACCOUNTDISABLE = 1; //the bit 1 has the ACCOUNTDISABLE flag 
begin
  CurrentUAC := TADOQuery1.FieldByName('userAccountControl').AsInteger;
  //Accept only those records without the ACCOUNTDISABLE flag
  Accept := CurrentUAC and (1 shl ACCOUNTDISABLE) = 0; 
end;
```